# In MacVim, how do I disable arrow keys in insert mode?

Tags: vim, macvim

I have added this to my `.vimrc`:

```
nnoremap <up> <nop>
nnoremap <down> <nop>
nnoremap <left> <nop>
nnoremap <right> <nop>
inoremap <up> <nop>
inoremap <down> <nop>
inoremap <left> <nop>
inoremap <right> <nop>
```

This works in normal and visual mode, but I can still use arrows in insert mode.

I'm using [Janus](https://github.com/carlhuda/janus) to set up my vim.

I'm a two-week convert, so my vim foo is limited. Is this a MacVim-related issue? Is Janus' configuration somehow getting in the way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first thing to do is to try to determine if your mappings are defined as you expect:

```
:verbose imap <up>
:verbose imap <down>
```

...etc.

This will show you what the current insert mode mapping is for your keys, and—if they are somehow being overridden—where they were defined.

Comment: This is a sample output I get. Not sure what to make of it. Is the autoclose plugin the culprit? i  <Down>      *@<C-R>=<SNR>23_FlushBuffer()<CR><Down>
        Last set from ~/.vim/plugin/autoclose.vim
i  <Down>      * <Nop>
        Last set from ~/.vimrc.local
Press ENTER or type command to continue

Comment: Yes, this shows that the autoclose plugin is resetting the mappings.  You can probably safely edit that file and comment out the lines that define the arrow key mappings, using a leading double quote character.

Comment: Thanks! Note to Janus users: Move remapping to `.gvimrc.local`.